# Collect URL.pathname from user input and append to existing url

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to Collect URL.pathname from user input and add to existing url, but when I do so, it doesn't seem to work when I output new URL.

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <input id="inputId" type="search" placeholder="Enter BSC Contract Address...">

  <button onclick="getEndString()" id="submit" type="submit">Go</button>
</form>
```

```js
let apiUrl = new URL('https://api.pancakeswap.info');

let myInput = document.getElementById("inputId");
let myForm = document.getElementById("myForm");

apiUrl.pathname = `/api/v2/tokens/` + getEndString(myInput.value);

function getEndString(x) {
  return x;
}

myForm.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(apiUrl.toString());
});
```

Comment: What is the `getEndString()` function supposed to do?

Comment: It's supposed to collect the input value and append to the URL pathname in order to create a new URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `onclick` listener from the `<button>` element.

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <input id="inputId" type="search" placeholder="Enter BSC Contract Address...">

  <button id="submit" type="submit">Go</button>
</form>
```

Move the assignement of the `pathname` into the event handler. The reason for this is that you want to read the `value` of the input and create the value for the `pathname` whenever you submit. Doing it outside of the event handler will only trigger the assignment whenever the script is loaded, but not after that.

```js
let apiUrl = new URL('https://api.pancakeswap.info');
let myInput = document.getElementById("inputId");
let myForm = document.getElementById("myForm");

myForm.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  apiUrl.pathname = `/api/v2/tokens/` + myInput.value;

  console.log(apiUrl.toString());
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Never even thought of it that way. It's now working okay.